# Adding a file to the class path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have a comment written in the code i am working on which says the filename can reside anywhere in the class path

how do i add the filename/file to this classpath in eclipse?

thanks

Comment: to be more specific what is your project type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have a standard Java project, create the file inside the `src` folder. Files in this folder are "on the classpath".

Answer (score 1):

In the project there is a file called .classpath with entries like:

`<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>`

Just adapt it to your needs.

Graphically you can do it through the project properties -> build path -> source's tab.